# How to make sure I have a "blank" request for home page in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In MVC there is a whole fancy routing engine, which works very well and directs requests to /home/index (for "empty") requests.

I need to support some horrible legacy code and sometimes I need to do special things when QueryString and/or path is not empty.

How do I know (When I'm in /home/index) that the actual request is:

1. To the root of the website
2. Without any kind of parameters?

My attempt:

```
if (Request.QueryString.HasKeys() || Request.Path.Length > 1)
```

Comment: For the path, why don't you add additional and more specific routes? For the query string, without knowing what "special things" need to happen, an [action filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381609(v=vs.100).aspx) could be a good candidate (where you will expect the query string and trigger logic, redirect or whatever).

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks, problem is I don't know all the "special things" either. I just want to send all weird looking requests to the .aspx pages that used to handle them, while i migrate to mvc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Controller for the given method that is returning the view you want to be redirected to, if there are query string parameters that you need to reference, include them as parameters:

```
public ActionResult Index(int someValue, string someText)
{
return View();
}
```

If you need to go to Index whether these query string parameters have been included, either

1. Make the parameters optional.
2. Overload the method with no parameters specified.

Comment: hi chad, thanks, but the problem is that the mvc code is perfect, no parameters or query string stuff, and the old asp.net code is horrible. I want to send all requests that have a querystring and/or path to a .aspx page. this answer allows me to do the opposite, and while handy, doesn't solve my issue..